# movetothread is in accessible

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following class:

```
class commMonitor : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    commMonitor();
    ~commMonitor();
private:
    QMap<unsigned short int, QTimer*> Monitors;
    QTimer* currTimer;
public slots:
    void createMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void deleteMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void startMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void stopMonitor(unsigned short int);

};
```

when I tried to do the following:

```
commMonitor* commOverWatch = new commMonitor();
QThread* monitorThread = new QThread();
commOverWatch->moveToThread(monitorThread);
```

the visual studio won't compile, and the error is the QObject::moveToThread is inaccessible.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ `class commMonitor : QObject` means private inheritance (by default), so you can't use public members in your case. I hope you are familiar with  inheritance rules. If no, [see this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance) As you can see, in your case, `moveToThread()` is a private method and of course you can't access it outside the class.

Solution: specify public inheritance explicitly:

```
class commMonitor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    commMonitor();
    ~commMonitor();
private:
    QMap<unsigned short int, QTimer*> Monitors;
    QTimer* currTimer;
public slots:
    void createMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void deleteMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void startMonitor(unsigned short int);
    void stopMonitor(unsigned short int);

};
```